# Simple comparison condition is not working in JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I stored some values in input hidden elements in HTML

```
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="1659" />
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="1569" />
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="1699" />
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="500" />

<div id="max_num"></div>
```

Then I am trying to access maximum value by this JavaScript function

```
function decre_incoming_troops()
{
    //Selecting all elements of class w_e_t_t_c_d
    var incoming_troops = $('input:hidden.w_e_t_t_c_d');
    var lastReach = 0;
    for(var i = 0; i < incoming_troops.length; i++)
    {
        if(incoming_troops[i].value > lastReach)
        {
            lastReach = incoming_troops[i].value;
        }
        document.getElementById("max_num").innerHTML = lastReach;
    }
}

decre_incoming_troops();
```

But unexpectedly this function is not giving maximum value.

I debugged it in detail and fined that this `if(incoming_troops[i].value > lastReach)` comparison condition is returning wrong result.

I don't know that is there any bug or logical error in the code.

Here is running example in [FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/M_Rashid/ub5pw6r8/1/)

Or you can check the same here in snippet below

```js
function decre_incoming_troops()
{
    //Selecting all elements of class w_e_t_t_c_d
 var incoming_troops = $('input:hidden.w_e_t_t_c_d');
 var lastReach = 0;
 for(var i = 0; i < incoming_troops.length; i++)
 {
        if(incoming_troops[i].value > lastReach)
        {
            lastReach = incoming_troops[i].value;
        }
        document.getElementById("max_num").innerHTML = lastReach;
 }
}

decre_incoming_troops();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="1659" />
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="1569" />
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="1699" />
<input type="hidden" class="w_e_t_t_c_d" value="500" />

<div id="max_num"></div>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: FYI - I think you could use something like: `Math.max.apply(Math, $("input:hidden.w_e_t_t_c_d").map(function () { return $(this).val(); }).get())` to get the max value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're performing lexicographic comparison on string values. Instead, you should convert to an integer:

```
parseInt(incoming_troops[i].value, 10)
```

I fixed the fiddle for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/ub5pw6r8/2/

```
var lastReach = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < incoming_troops.length; i++) {
    var x = parseInt(incoming_troops[i].value, 10);  // Base-10 conversion.
    if (x > lastReach) {
        lastReach = x;                               // Current maximum.
    }
}  // When the loop is done, we have the overall maximum. Now display it.
document.getElementById("max_num").innerHTML = lastReach;
```

Answer (score 0):

The value you got from the tag is a string.  You need it to be a number.

if(new Number(incoming_troops[i].value) > lastReach)

parseInt() as stated also works.

Also you only have to set the DOM element if you have found a larger number
current = new Number(incoming_troops[i].value)

`if(current > lastReach)
        {
            lastReach = current;
            document.getElementById("max_num").innerHTML = lastReach;
        }`